# Why does the shadow host get focus even with delegatesFocus being false?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component, shadow-dom

Consider the following example:

```js
let template = document.querySelector('.quote-template').innerHTML;
let shadowElement = document.querySelector('.quote-app');
let shadow = shadowElement.attachShadow({
  mode: 'open'
});

shadow.innerHTML = `
  <style>
    .quote {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 25px 40px;
      background-color: #000;
      font-weight: 300;
      line-height: 24px;
      color: #fff;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .quote:focus {
            color: red;
        }
  </style>
  ${template}   
`;
console.log(document.querySelector('.quote-app').shadowRoot.delegatesFocus)
```

```css
.quote-app:focus {
  outline: 2px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<template class="quote-template">
  <div class="quote">
    Use mouse right click on the test button and you will see red outline on the shadow root.
    <button>Test focus</button>
  </div>
</template>

<div class="quote-app"></div>
```

As you can notice, when the "test focus" button gets focus, the parent shadow host also get `:focus` styles. Now, the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/delegatesFocus) say that

> If **true(delegatesFocus)**, when a non-focusable part of the shadow DOM is clicked, the first focusable part is given focus, and the **shadow host is given any available :focus styling**.

It doesn't say anything about when a *focusable part* gets focused. Here in my scenario `delegatesFocus` is false, why does the shadow host get the `:focus` styling?

---

P.S: The observed behaviour contradicts [google web.dev's documentation](https://web.dev/shadowdom-v1/#handling-focus). They mention:

> If you were to set delegatesFocus: false, here's what you would see instead:

[image]

The outer black dotted outline turns into red in reality, contradicting the image.

Comment: The documentation is incorrect or incomplete in some places. Have you seen a difference when using a defined Custom Element, instead of this shadowRoot on a DIV?